# How to make :ExpandableListView orientation with horizontal

Tags: android

I would  to the ExpandableListView  layout  like that:

```
########
   ###   ### ###
########
   ###   ### ###
########
```

How can I do?
  I  would to make the  ExpandableListView's child Item layout   with horizontal

Answer (score 2):

There's no support for that in the existing ExpandableListView. To do that, you're probably going to have to write your own widget.